# How to give input to a script which is getting run by puppet manifest

Tags: puppet, foreman

I have configured foreman puppet in my private network, I have attached a host to it. I wrote a module like this:
This is the hello.pp

```
class hello{
    file { 'xyz':
            ensure => present,
            owner => 'root',
            group => 'root',
            mode => '0775',
            path => '/tmp/input.py',
            source => 'puppet:///modules/py/input.py',
            notify => Exec['abc'],
        }
exec {'abc':
           command => 'usr/bin/python /tmp/input.py',
           require => File['xyz'],
           refreshonly => true,
           logoutput => true,
    }
}
```

My input.py is like this:

```
print 'hello'
print 'enter your name: '
x=raw_input()
print x
```

I'm calling this file using puppet manifest. the file is copied to the host in the tmp folder but is not asking for input for execution. Any idea how can I make it work? I want to pass the input. Is it possible to pass the parameter in the foreman for that particular module?
this is the puppet output I'm getting on the host:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Hello/Exec[abc]/returns: hello world
Notice: /Stage[main]/Hello/Exec[abc]/returns: enter your name:
Notice: /Stage[main]/Hello/Exec[abc]/returns: Traceback (most recent call last):
Notice: /Stage[main]/Hello/Exec[abc]/returns: File "tmp/input.py", line 3, in <module>
Notice: /Stage[main]/Hello/Exec[abc]/returns: x=raw_input()
Notice: /Stage[main]/Hello/Exec[abc]/returns: EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Error: /Stage[main]/Hello/Exec[abc]/returns: Failed to call refresh: /usr/bin/python /tmp/input.py returned 1 instaed of one of [0]
Error: /Stage[main]/Hello/Exec[abc]/returns: /usr/bin/python /tmp/input.py returned 1 instaed of one of [0]
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.86 seconds
```

Any idea to make it work with any workaround related to coding would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? `raw_input` is a function for taking information from stdin, and requires a prompt. There's a number of ways to stub stdin and give it a variable, but I think it'd be easier to just change the script to the following:

```
from sys import argv
print 'hello'
print 'enter your name: '
x=argv[1]
print x
```

Then change your exec to:

```
exec {'abc':
  command => "/usr/bin/python /tmp/input.py ${python_name}",
  require => File['xyz'],
  refreshonly => true,
  logoutput => true,
}
```

Then add a parameter to the class:

```
class hello (
  $python_name,
)
```

Then you could change the $python name parameter in Foreman and get the result you wanted.

Comment: Thanks peter i understand now how to do it. i followed the same procedure what you told but when i run puppet agent -t -v on the host, i m getting this error: Notice: /Stage[main]/Hello/Exec[abc]/returns: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: can you look at the issue

Comment: That implies that the $python_name variable is blank, did you give a value to the parameter in the class?

Comment: actually i gave it a value in the foreman and saved it, how can it be blank? do i need to provide any default value also? if so, how?

Comment: in the class i didnt give it any value, only in the foreman in smart calss variables, i gave it a value by overriding the default behaviour